# Can I create a many to many relationship in memory?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

My application stores a series of changes, and often I aggregate those changes into the current state to display to the user. I have two entities, **ProductChange** and **AssetClassChange**.

The change data comes from a database, but I've created client-side models to store the aggregated data: **ProductSnapshot** and **AssetClassSnapshot**. These snapshots are related to each other as a many-to-many relationship.

My question is, what's the best way to achieve this relationship in the code? As I go through the aggregation, I could store copies of the related entities on each other, but that'd be a lot of duplication (they're read-only, so it'd just be a performance concern). Alternatively I suppose I could generate ids and fill some third data structure to store the relationships, which the entities could use to look up each other - but this seems like a lot of work.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a persistent data structure for this task due to its memory efficiency and store a third mapping structure for the relationships.

We are having a talk on this subject on [this GitHub issue page](https://github.com/samsquire/multiversion-concurrency-control/issues/1#issuecomment-1106790543)